# Spring Data Projection doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

It looks like Spring-Data projections don't works properly. Also the @CreationDate annotated fields are nulls. What's wrong with that?

This is Category entity class:

```
package api.product.domain;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Set;

    @Entity
    @Getter
    @DynamicUpdate
    @EqualsAndHashCode(of = "name")
    @NoArgsConstructor
    class Category {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "ID_GENERATOR")
        private Long id;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private Set<Product> products;

        @Setter
        @Accessors(chain = true)
        @Column(unique = true, length = 20, nullable = false)
        private String name;

        @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
        @JoinColumn(name = "parent_category_id")
        @Setter
        @Accessors(chain = true)
        private Category parentCategory;

        @CreatedDate
        @Setter
        private LocalDateTime creationDate;

        @LastModifiedDate
        @Setter
        private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

        Category(String name, Category parentCategory){
            this.name = name;
            this.parentCategory = parentCategory;
        }
    }
```

The projection's interface:

```
public interface ShowCategoryDto {
    @Value("#{target.id}")
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Set<ProductBasicDto> getProducts();
}
```

And Repository:

```
interface CategoryRepository extends Repository<Category, Long> {

    Set<ShowCategoryDto> findAll();

    Optional<ShowCategoryDto> findOptionalById(Long id);

    Category save(Category category);

    Optional<Category> getOneById(Long id);

    void removeById(Long id);
}
```

Now when I call the `findAll` method it returns:

```
creationDate:null
id:1
lastModifiedDate:null
name:"wwwwwwwwww"
parentCategory:null
products:[]
```

So I see two problems here. The first one is that projection isn't applied, and the second one is that there are nulls in the `creationDate` and `lastModifiedDate` fields. Does someone know the reason why this happens and could share it with me?

Comment: did you try adding the entity listener?

Comment: Nope, I didn't see anyting about that in Spring-Data documentation, is it necessary?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436558/auto-generating-create-date-and-last-modify-date-using-jpa-data-crudrepositories

Comment: oh great, thanks guys :) One problem solved :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `findAll` is the method of CrudRepository interface, its [signature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAll--) is:

```
List<T> findAll()
```

where `T` is your **entity**.

If you need a custom method that return projections instead of the entities you should use another name for the method, for example:

```
List<MyProjection> findBy()
List<MyProjection> findAllBy()
List<MyProjection> findProjectionsBy()
List<MyProjection> getProjectionsBy()
```

etc.

More info:

[Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)
[Working with projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)